# Dynamically add and remove formgroup in formarray angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Im trying to dynamically add and remove formgroup to a formarray using a counter component. There are 4 counter components in a for-loop which have a category. When the user clicks on add button, the counter increments and adds a formgroup to the formarray. No problem there.

But now I'm stuck with deleting the right formgroup. When a user clicks on the delete button on the formgroup or decrements the counter I want to remove the right group. So on decrement I need the last formgroup in that category to be deleted, and on on delete button click, I want the counter to decrement 1 and remove the formgroup.

This is what I have so far:

form component

```js
 profileForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
      Age: new FormControl(0),
      PartnerAge: new FormControl(0),
      Children: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  
  }

 childRange = ScheidenChildRange;
  childList = [
    this.childRange.ZeroToThree,
    this.childRange.FourToTwelve,
    this.childRange.ThirteenToSeventeen,
    this.childRange.OlderThanEighteen,
  ];

get ChildrenArray() {
    return this.profileForm.get("Children") as FormArray;
  }

  initChildRow(age) {
    return this.fb.group({
      Age: new FormControl(age),
      BSOOrVSO: new FormControl(null),
      BSOOrVSOCostsPerMonth: new FormControl(null),
      BSOOrVSOHoursAWeek: new FormControl(null),
      Childminder: new FormControl(null),
      ChildminderCostsPerMonth: new FormControl(null),
      ChildminderHoursAWeek: new FormControl(null),
      FormalChildcare: new FormControl(null),
    });
  }

  addChild(count: number, childRange: ScheidenChildRange) {
    this.ChildrenArray.push(this.initChildRow(childRange));
    this.onInputChange.next();
  }

  removeChild(age: any) {
    const index = this.ChildrenArray.controls.findIndex(
      (c) => c.value.Age === age.index
    );
    this.ChildrenArray.removeAt(index);
    this.removeEvent.next(age);
    this.onInputChange.next();
  }
```

```html
        <counter *ngFor="let child of childList | keyvalue; index as i" (incremented)="addChild($event, child.value)"
          (decremented)="removeChild($event)" [decrementEvent]="removeEvent.asObservable()" [index]="i" [max]="5"
          [label]="child.value | getChildRange">
        </counter>


    <div formArrayName="Children">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let child of ChildrenArray.controls; index as i">
        <child-questions *ngIf="child.get('Age').value === 0 || child.get('Age').value === 1"
          [Descriptions]="Descriptions" [formGroupName]="i" [Index]="i" [form]="child"
          (removeChildEv)="removeChild($event)" (inputChanged)="radioChecked()">
        </child-questions>
```

counter component

```js
increment() {
    if (this.counter === this.max) {
      return;
    }
    this.counter += 1;
    this.incremented.emit({ count: this.counter, index: this.index });
  }

  decrement() {
    if (
      (!this.negativeAllowed && this.counter === 0) ||
      this.counter < this.min
    ) {
      return;
    }
    this.counter -= 1;
    this.decremented.emit({ count: this.counter, index: this.index });
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.decrementEvent) {
      this.eventsSubscription = this.decrementEvent.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log("Counter", data);
        if (this.index === data.index) {
          this.decrement();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @HostListener("unloaded")
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.eventsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link with your issue? it would be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

To remove FormGroup from FormArray, simply pass the FormGroup index to the function.

In the template:

```
    <div formArrayName="Children">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let child of ChildrenArray.controls; index as i">
    <child-questions *ngIf="child.get('Age').value === 0 || child.get('Age').value === 1"
      [Descriptions]="Descriptions" [formGroupName]="i" [Index]="i" [form]="child"
      (removeChildEv)="removeChild($event,i)" (inputChanged)="radioChecked()">
    </child-questions>
```

In the removeChild function:

```
removeChild(age: any, index: number) {
  this.ChildrenArray.removeAt(index);
  this.removeEvent.next(age);
  this.onInputChange.next();
}
```